# Navigating into next page on windows phone using global app bar

Tags: windows

I have successfully creating global app bar but not able to navigate to next page. I have used two kind of code.

First

```
(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(
   new Uri("/CategoryPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
);
```

Second

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SignupPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

and both gave us error using second not able to compile the code, and first one gave us error after run.

And also, i have read many times in windows phone developer but not find any way to navigate the next page. So any suggestion to navigate using global app other wise we need to add duplicate code on every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for stakoverflow member to view my problem and now i have resolved the problem. The main problem was "object sender, EventArgs e", actually we used some other instead of "EventArgs", so event should be private void SearchAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) look like this.

Thanks all and love to stackoverflow which provide us great solutions